# Google sheets - join one value to each value in comma separated list and generate a single list of the results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a list like the following in Google Sheets (2 columns)

```
    _A_ _B_________________________________
_1_ 932 a@email.com,b@email.com
_2_ 343 c@email.com,d@email.com,e@email.com
_3_ 198 
_4_ 197 f@email.com
_5_ 231 g@email.com,h@email.com
```

I want to generate a single list like this...

```
    _A_ _B_________
_1_ 932 a@email.com
_2_ 932 b@email.com
_3_ 343 c@email.com
_4_ 343 d@email.com
_5_ 343 e@email.com
_6_ 197 f@email.com
_7_ 231 g@email.com
_8_ 231 h@email.com
```

So far, I've managed to make this in C1...

```
=arrayformula(IF(B2:B5="","",concat(A2:A5,CONCAT("|",split(B2:B5,",")))))
```

...which generates this...

```
    _A_ _B_________________________________ _C_____________ _D_____________ _E_____________
_1_ 932 a@email.com,b@email.com             932|a@email.com 932|b@email.com 932|
_2_ 343 c@email.com,d@email.com,e@email.com 343|c@email.com 343|d@email.com 343|e@email.com
_3_ 198                                     198|            198|            198|
_4_ 197 f@email.com                         197|f@email.com 197|            197|
_5_ 231 g@email.com,h@email.com             231|g@email.com 231|h@email.com 231|
```

... and now I am very stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula

```
=QUERY(arrayformula(IFERROR(SPLIT(flatten(IF(B2:B="","",concat(A2:A,CONCAT("|",split(B2:B,","))))),"|"))),"where Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

**How the added functions work**

The key function here is the (undocumented) `flatten` function.
When we use `flatten` on an array of cells, it **transposes the array row by row into a single column**.

Please notice the **difference between `flatten` and `TRANSPOSE`**

```
+------+-----+----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| array of cells  | =flatten(A1:C2) |  =TRANSPOSE(A1:C2)  |
+------+-----+----+-----------------+----------+----------+
|   1  |  2  |  3 |        1        |     1    |     4    |
|   4  |  5  |  6 |        2        |     2    |     5    |
|      |     |    |        3        |     3    |     6    |
|      |     |    |        4        |          |          |
|      |     |    |        5        |          |          |
|      |     |    |        6        |          |          |
+------+-----+----+-----------------+----------+----------+
```

Once we get everything in one column we use `SPLIT` once again and finally the `QUERY` function to get rid of the rows without a value in the second column.
The `IFERROR` function is not actually needed it here but we usually apply it as a precautionary measure.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592)

Comment: Amazing - thank you. Can you please explain how this works, step by step?

Comment: I will later on. Please give me some time. I have to be away for a couple of hours :(

Comment: Thank you - no rush! You have saved my hours of work!

Comment: So, as I brief explanation to this answer: If in the range of column B there are comman separated values he first uses ```split(B2:B,",")``` the user is splitting those cells with two separate email addresses. Then he concats all cells in column B and then he concats all cells in column A adding between each value the delimitor ```|```.  Then he flattens the array of values he has and then he splits these values based on the delimitor ```|```. Finally he queries to order values alphabetically in regards to column B and makes sure that col B is not null.

Comment: *"You have saved my hours of work!"* Glad I could help  *"Can you please explain how this works"*  Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @MrMills It should be mentioned that FLATTEN() is an undocumented function discovered recently by a user (March 2020). https://support.google.com/docs/thread/33715001?hl=en It's believed it is intended to remain "hidden" in the back end of the sheets programming, but there is no guarantee that the formula will continue to work indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps

```
=query(ArrayFormula(split(flatten(A:A&"_"&split(B1:B, ",")), "_")), "where Col2 <>''")
```

[image]

Comment: .. and it avoids the 50000 character limit of concat().