# Getting column data and re-arranging it in rows, with a pattern, using formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a worksheet of multiple sheets, I have `Sheet1`, e.g. with the following: (these rows will be less or more and are manually entered)

**Sheet1**

```
        A           B       C       
1       APPLE       ORANGE  LEMON   
2       bravo       chair   mars    
3       charlie     table   jupiter 
4       alpha       box     venus   
5       delta               saturn  
6       foxtrot
```

I would like some help in constructing `Sheet2` via formulas so that it rearranges data from `Sheet1` as follows

**Sheet2 (Desired result)**

```
        A       B       
1       APPLE           
2               bravo   
3               charlie 
4               alpha   
5               delta   
6               foxtrot 
7                       
8       ORANGE          
9               chair   
10              table   
11              box     
12                      
13      LEMON           
14              mars    
15              jupiter 
16              venus   
17              saturn
```

It probably needs some combination of `QUERY()` `ARRAYFORMULA()`, `TRANSPOSE()` and/or `INDEX()` but I need some help with getting started and having them into lesser columns (and more rows.) as shown. Please note that `Sheet1`'s data will keep changing in number of rows (or columns) so `Sheet2` needs to adapt to that.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you be open for a solution in App Script? This seems easy to do programmatic but kind of hard and convoluted with formula.

Comment: @Raserhin I can do it in AppScript myself. But I'd like a formula approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    {FILTER(
        FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A:F)=1;A:F;"")));
        FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A:F))<>"")
    \FILTER(
        FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A:F)<>1;A:F;"")));
        FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A:F))<>"")}
)
```

if you use semicolon as function argument separator.

If you use comma, change to

```
=ArrayFormula(
   {FILTER(
       FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A:F)=1,A:F,""))),
       FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A:F))<>"")
   ,FILTER(
       FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A:F)<>1,A:F,""))),
       FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A:F))<>"")}
)
```

The formula will run faster if you specify a row constraint.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. I didn't know about `FLATTEN` at all. Is this an undocumented function? Thanks! :)

Comment: Oops.. forgot to notice that this solution doesn't insert extra blank rows in between blocks, (as required in my desired result), but I'll try to figure out how to insert them myself. (Please feel free to modify the answer, it is still accepted.)  Thank you again!

Comment: @spcsLrg Yes, it is undocumented. You can read about ```FLATTEN``` [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/flatten-function-in-google-sheets/)

Comment: Blank rows are filtered out by ```FILTER``` function. You can simulate blanks if you enter ```space``` in the first blank cell in each col in source table.

Comment: You can also see the differences/similarities between `FLATTEN` and `TRANSPOSE` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485161/1527780).